# Control the same application from different tabs

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, single-page-application, store

I have a React-Redux application with two components. One component (`<App/>`) **displays the store values**, and the other component (`<Panel/>`) **controls the values** by dispatching actions, but each of them runs on a different route, as below:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/panel" component={Panel} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I open each route in a different browser tab:

- App Component: http://localhost:3000
- Panel Component: http://localhost:3000/panel

What I want to achieve is to modify a value insde the Panel page (by dispatching a Redux action) and to automatically see the updated value on the App page.

Is that possible or I am basically running two different instances of the application?

Comment: You are correct, you are running two separate instances of your app. However, you can use [Firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase) with redux to do exactly what you described.

Comment: I don't know if Firebase is the best option or not, but you should look into **real-time apps**. You are not gonna get local sync for those tabs.